# Firebase admin retrieve authentication token for testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get a JWT to authenticate into firebase emulator as an user for a test suite via firebase admin. The emulator is running what firebase calls a << demo >> project, so it will not hit the real endpoint.

currently I've tried creating a custom token

```
    const user = await admin.auth().createUser({ uid: randomUUID() });
    const jwt = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.uid);
```

But I get:

<< Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "demo-test" but got "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit"  >>

I also tried creating a jwt via https://jwt.io , since the firebase doc says explicitely [With the environment variable set, Firebase Admin SDKs will accept unsigned ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks):

but if I get :

<< Firebase ID token has invalid signature. >>

Answer (score 0):

I get this error only if i try to verify the token generated by `createCustomToken`.

If you pass the token to `signInWithCustomToken` in the client app then get the user token with `auth.currentUser.getIdToken` your will notice the token is slightly different and claims are the expected ones.

You can then verify this token in your backend and no errors will show up as it will be getting the correct aud.